# Manually update UITableView (Replace NSFetchedResultsController logic)

Tags: uitableview, fetch

i **used** a combination of queue and resultscontroller to update and display some coredata objects. I got some exceptions and problems (See this thread [NSOperationQueue and NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168361/nsoperationqueue-and-nsfetchedresultscontroller)). After long research i found out that NSFetchedResultsController is the problem and i decided to write my own update logic for uitableview.

My new strategie is:
- When my view loads i fetch all objects from core data into a array and display them
- After 20 Seconds i try to load new data from web and update core data (Inside of a second thread / or nsoperation) This thread uses his own objectcontext... my main context will ignore any changes!
- After that i fetch my objects again but in temporary array
- Now i need to update my uitableview but i don't know how... i have to compare both arrays and do update, delete or insert cells..

Its important for me to have this nice animations for insert and delete. I my case all objects are only in one section!! But it could be possible that i have a view with "Cars" and "Hotels" => 2 Sections but different objects (2 datasource arrays)

Can someone please provide me a good example for updating a uitableview.

I used:

```m
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

I need to replace `NSFetchedResultsController` logic.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This might be too simple of an answer, but I have used

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

And stuck it into - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated method.

Comment: viewWillAppear is called only one time... and reloadData does not animated inserts and deletes :(